# Would I need to do anmeldung and get aufenthaltstitel if I come to Germany on a student visa, but leave quite early on?

Tags: germany, student-visa

Let's suppose I go to Germany on a student applicant visa, spend maybe less than two weeks there, would I need to do anmeldung still?

Normally people say that you don't need to do anmeldung if you're on a short stay. BUt, when people speak of short, stay, I believe, they assume that the person enters Germany on a tourist visa. My doubt  arises because I am entering on a student applicant visa but staying for short.

---

## Context

I have taken the student applicant visa on basis of writing an entrance exam. I have two exams on consecutive days and it takes one month for result to come, so I thought it'd be cheaper for me to return back to my home country. In this, I am in doubt if I need to do all these things for the short period of stay

Comment: Are you planning to return to Germany in this scenario, or are you asking about what happens if you decide to abandon your studies after two weeks?

Comment: If you live in a pension/hotel the registration is done for you. If you rent an apartment, which is mostly long term, you must register yourself.

Comment: See, the basic problem is, I have taken the student visa on basis of writing an entrance exam. I have two exams on consectuvie days and it takes one month for result to come, so I thought it'd be cheaper for me to return back to my home country. In this, I am in doubt if I need to do all these things for the short period of stay @phoog

Comment: What if it's something like an AirBnB or something @MarkJohnson

Comment: Are you saying your study course will last two weeks max? Do you already have your study visa?  Is it a Student Applicant visa? https://www.germany-visa.org/student-visa/student-applicant-visa/

Comment: AirBnB is for short term renting. You will (or should) have filled out a **Meldeschein** when you arrived. That is the registration. Nothing more needs to be done.

Comment: Yes Student applicant visa @Traveller

Comment: Registration law has nothing to do with Immigration law. Accommodation establishments (AirBnB, pensions, hotels) where you pay something to stay there, mostly for up to 3 months, have different rules than when you yourself rent (with a renting contract) a residence. There is no registration requirement for stays with friends (where there is no payment). If you are using AirBnB, you should add that to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. § 17 (1) [BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/index.html) obligates *everyone* to register with the registration office *within two weeks* after moving in into an apartment (§ 20 BMG).
2. The registration obligation is suspended for the first sixth months for those who are already registered *somewhere* *in* Germany, § 27 (2) 1, 2 BMG or § 29 (1) 1 BMG.
3. You are, however, as of yet not registered in Germany.
   For people who normally reside abroad the obligation is still suspended, but only for the *first three months*, § 27 (2) 3 BMG or § 29 (1) 2 BMG.
4. Bottom line:

   - It is not forbidden to register.
     Registration will, however, inevitably necessitate *de*registration, § 17 (2) BMG.
   - You can skip the red tape for stays lasting less than three months at one place.